# Else command in batch running all at once?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, wmic

I'm not sure why this is happening, but it seems like the else command in this batch script I'm working on is running all at once, instead of one line at a time. Any suggestions?

```
set getprocesslistlocal=wmic process get name,processid,workingsetsize
echo Type the name of the remote machine to view processes of (or type local for local machine), and press Enter.
set /P remotemachine=
if %remotemachine%==local (
%getprocesslistlocal%
) else (
echo Type the user name to access %remotemachine% with, then press Enter.
set /P remoteuser=
echo Type the password for %remoteuser% on %remotemachine%, then press Enter. ^(Will be displayed in plaintext^)
set /P remotepassword=
wmic /node:%remotemachine% /user:%remoteuser% /password:%remotepass% process get name,processid
)
echo End of list.
pause
echo Type the process id to terminate and hit Enter.
set /P killid=
if %remotemachine%==local (
wmic process where processid="%killid%" call terminate
) else (
wmic /node %remotemachine% /user:%remoteuser% /password:%remotepass% process where processid="%killid%" call terminate
)
echo Process id %killid% terminated.
pause
```

Comment: I assume you meant the first else in the batch file?  What exactly do you mean the else command is running all at once?  Do you mean that it never stops to let you enter anything for the two `set /P` commands? You should describe more clearly what happens (and what you expect to happen).

Comment: I recieve "Invalid user ID", which I assume is from the other commands being entered. Once I enter the `remoteuser`, it does not appear in the next line. This user does indeed exist, and the command works fine with this user and password when out of batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"it seems like the else command in this batch script I'm working on is running all at once, instead of one line at a time."*

But you do have a problem with your first ELSE block.

Normal expansion using `%var%` occurs when the statement is parsed, and your entire IF/ELSE construct is parsed all at once. So your ELSE block is seeing the values of `%remoteuser%` and `%remotepass%` that existed prior to the execution of the SET /P statements that set the values. Obviously not what you want.

The problem is easily solved by using delayed expansion. Delayed expansion must first be enabled by using SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion, then you expand variables at execution time by using `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

You also must be consistent with your variable names, as Michael Burr has pointed out in his answer.

I haven't tested, but I believe the following will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set getprocesslistlocal=wmic process get name,processid,workingsetsize
echo Type the name of the remote machine to view processes of (or type local for local machine), and press Enter.
set /P remotemachine=
if %remotemachine%==local (
  %getprocesslistlocal%
) else (
  echo Type the user name to access %remotemachine% with, then press Enter.
  set /P remoteuser=
  echo Type the password for !remoteuser! on %remotemachine%, then press Enter. ^(Will be displayed in plaintext^)
  set /P remotepass=
  wmic /node:%remotemachine% /user:!remoteuser! /password:!remotepass! process get name,processid
)
echo End of list.
pause
echo Type the process id to terminate and hit Enter.
set /P killid=
if %remotemachine%==local (
  wmic process where processid="%killid%" call terminate
) else (
  wmic /node %remotemachine% /user:%remoteuser% /password:%remotepass% process where processid="%killid%" call terminate
)
echo Process id %killid% terminated.
pause
```

For more information about delayed expansion, type `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from the command prompt and beginning reading about halfway down with the paragraph that begins *"Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added."*

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. Your code does indeed work, and I will certainly use delayed expansion from now on (when needed).

Answer (score 1):

It think the problem is a simple typo in the password variable.  When entered. the variable name used is `remotepassword`, when used in the `wmic` command the name used is `remotepass` so it will always be blank:

```
set /P remotepassword=
rem    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
wmic /node:%remotemachine% /user:%remoteuser% /password:%remotepass% process get name,processid
rem                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This was a problem, but not the only problem. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `if`  or `for` code block you need delayed expansion and `!variables!`  for all variables with changing values. Example:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
...
) else (
echo Type the user name to access %remotemachine% with, then press Enter.
set /P remoteuser=
echo Type the password for !remoteuser! on %remotemachine%, then press Enter. ^(Will be displayed in plaintext^)
set /P remotepassword=
wmic /node:%remotemachine% /user:!remoteuser! /password:!remotepass! process get name,processid
)
```